# How to enable http2 on 16.04

Tags: apache2.4

I've been waiting and waiting for the new release of Ubuntu so I could finally get a more up to date version of apache for http2. FINALLY upgraded (after stupid issues with the updater) and I don't see the http2 module anywhere. How do I enable http2? Please don't tell me it was it was left out because it's "experimental".

Comment: "Please don't tell me…", unfortunately, that's exactly the case. It's there in the [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes#HTTP.2F2_support_in_Apache_httpd).

Comment: That is very disappointing. So using Ubuntu still means no http2 support unless I compile my own I guess. That was the whole reason I started using Ubuntu instead of Slackware :-(

Comment: Use nginx instead of (or in front of) Apache, maybe. They haven't disabled in nginx: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-release-notes/+bug/1503051/

Comment: It seems it is the use case for the `snap` package format: find or create the package with the latest and greatest Apache version regardless what the rest of the system expects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ondrej's Launchpad PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/apache2):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I found this answer on DigitalOceans [community support](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/enable-http2-in-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04) site:

> Don't forget that after installing the new version of Apache, you need
>   to activate the module manually:
>
> ```
> sudo a2enmod http2
> ```
>
> In your Apache config file, you can either add
>   global support:
>
> ```
> Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
> ```
>
> Or you can activate it for individual,
>   secure vhosts:
>
> ```
> Protocols h2 http/1.1
> ```
>
> Restart Apache and you're all set. You can test
>   your server at https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test.